# Expanding variables in strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to use this to echo an image..

```
$actual_image_name = "image.png";  
var msg = '<img src=http://website.com/uploads/$actual_image_name />';
```

But everything i've tried isn't working. It's either coming back as something like "http://website.com/uploads/$actual_image_name" or some other path.

I know it's very simple but I need some help!
Thanks!

---

My full code;

```
function sendImg()
 {

$actual_image_name = "image.png";
var msg = "<img src=http://website.com/uploads/$actual_image_name />";




                    document.getElementById("chatmsg").value = "";
                    var url = "sendMsg.php?userId=" + userId + "&strangerId=" + strangerId + "&msg=" + msg;
                    xmlHttp6.open("POST", url, true);
                    xmlHttp6.onreadystatechange = stateChanged6;
                    xmlHttp6.send(null);



}
```

---

Comment: Where is this code being run? `var msg` isn't valid PHP syntax, so you should just be getting a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it.

Comment: Ah. That's not PHP, that's JavaScript. Whole different language, whole different syntax. There is no equivalent of PHP's double-quotes in JavaScript, you have to use `'string' + variable + 'other_string'`.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd say sending an entire HTML tag over AJAX like that is asking for trouble - it opens the way for security holes where someone could post arbitrary HTML and therefore JavaScript to another user... [Edit: just saw your comment below; maybe you have a sensible use case.]

Comment: So, how could I get the image link and send it?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you need to know, sorry. Are you saying that `$actual_image_name` needs to come from ... somewhere else?

Comment: Don't worry, i've got someone to take a look for me!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

You must use double quotes

```
$actual_image_name = "image.png";  
$msg = "<img src=http://website.com/uploads/$actual_image_name />";
```

See [PHP Strings documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

---

Test case:

```
$actual_image_name = "image.png";
$msg = "<img src=http://website.com/uploads/$actual_image_name />";
echo $msg;
```

Output:

```
<img src=http://website.com/uploads/image.png />
```

Comment: @RyanBoyling Is that a question? How is it not working, please provide details.

Comment: As suggested by @Agustín Dondo, `$msg` variable is missing a `$`

Comment: @RyanBoyling There must be something else. A simple test case proves that it works.

Comment: @RyanBoyling You're code makes absolutely no sense. What you pasted is javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how you use the quotes:

```
$actual_image_name = "image.png";  
$msg = '<img src="http://website.com/uploads/' . $actual_image_name . '" />';
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Since the downvoter didn't comment: you were most likely downvoted because the question is precisely about variable expansion inside strings, not concatenation.